# Can preorder, postorder and in order traversals be beneficial to a real time application?

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-tree, inorder, preorder, postorder

Sequences ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"] (preorder)
and ["B", "A", "E", "D", "F", "C"] (inorder)

What can relate to a real-life example application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Postorder**: Used to delete a tree.

**Inorder**: Used to print data in ordered (ascending) fashion.

**Preorder**: Used to create a copy of the tree.

Comment: got that, Thanks